# Copy objects in scala but changing "children" for rewriting

Tags: scala, copy, url-rewriting

In [kiama](http://code.google.com/p/kiama) a generic "dup" method [is defined](http://code.google.com/p/kiama/source/browse/src/org/kiama/rewriting/Rewriter.scala#312) which copies `Product` objects and applies a given function to each of the elements of the `Product` in order to support rewriting of `Term`s:

```
/**
 * General product duplication function.  Returns a product that applies
 * the same constructor as the product t, but with the given children            
 * instead of t's children.  Fails if a constructor cannot be found or
 * if one of the children is not of the appropriate type.
 */
private def dup (t : Product, children : Array[AnyRef]) : Product = {

    val ctor = (t.getClass.getConstructors())(0)
    try {
        val ret = ctor.newInstance (children : _*).asInstanceOf[Product]
        ret
                                                                                    } catch {
        case e : java.lang.ClassCastException =>
            error ("dup cast failed: " + t)
        case e : IllegalArgumentException =>
            error ("dup illegal arguments: " + ctor + " (" +
                   children.deep.mkString (",") + "), expects " +
                   ctor.getParameterTypes.length)
    }            
}
```

Used [like this](http://code.google.com/p/kiama/source/browse/src/org/kiama/rewriting/Rewriter.scala#359):

```
private def childProduct (p : Product, i : Int, s : => Strategy) : Option[Term] = {
    val numchildren = p.productArity
    val ct = p.productElement (i-1)
    val children = new Array[AnyRef](numchildren)
    for (j <- 0 until numchildren)
       children (j) = makechild (p.productElement (j))
       s (ct) match {
                case Some (ti) =>
                    children (i-1) = makechild (ti)
                case None      =>
                    return None
           }
    val ret = dup (p, children)
    Some (ret)
```

This gives some limitations on the usage.
I know they are working on replacing this mechanism ([Issue 2](http://code.google.com/p/kiama/issues/detail?id=2&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Component%20Reporter%20Summary), [Issue 31](http://code.google.com/p/kiama/issues/detail?id=31&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Component%20Reporter%20Summary)) but I think it might be interesting in hearing how you guys would do this?

For example will the `Positional` var(or any other var!) of scala parser combinators not be copied. In fact everything not part of the explict first constructor (and thereby also the default compiler generated `unapply` method).

I have been experimenting with providing some kind of trait or similar I could add to my terms that the dup/childProduct/etc methods could use, but to no luck yet. (I don't see how case class `copy` could be used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a small GitHub repository, [RSchulz/sbtr](http://github.com/RSchulz/sbtr), containing my modified Kiama `Rewriter.scala` module. In it you will find these files:

- `src/main/scala/rrs/sbtr/SBTR.scala` — My "Strategy-Based Term Rewriting" module
- `src/main/scala/rrs/sbtr/RewriterFmt.alacs` — The original code after formatting for my style conventions
- `src/main/scala/rrs/sbtr/Rewriter-0.8.alacs` — The slightly updated 0.8 version
- `src/main/scala/rrs/sbtr/Rewriter.alacs` — The original version from which I started

Diff-ing the first two will disclose my modifications, which should be easily back-ported into the current Kiama `Rewriter.scala` code.

The primary difference between the original and the 0.8 versions of the `Rewriter.scala` source are the addition of `queryf`, which I did carry over into `SBTR`. Changes subsequent to 0.8 have not been incorporated.

The suffix `.alacs` (scala spelled backwards) is used to keep those files from being compiled. To my knowledge, build tools and IDEs cannot be directed to ignore specific files (at least not easily).

Answer (score 3):

I use a modified version of the Kiama `Rewriter` module. It adds a `Constructable` trait that signifies that a value can `deconstruct` itself (make an array holding its constituents / children) and `reconstruct` a new instance from an array of constituents. When Kiama encounters a value that implements `Constructable` in one of the methods `dup`, `child`, `all` or `some`, it avoids the reflective code and instead uses `deconstruct` and `construct`.

In addition to freeing the client code from the requirement that types amenable to rewriting be derived from `Product`, it allows for a heterogeneous rewrite. In other words, the type coming out of a rewrite need not be precisely identical to the concrete type of the value that was rewritten.

The down-side is that the client code must define those `deconstruct` and `construct` methods.

(Lastly and not really germane to your question, I added an optimization that avoids building a new value if the result of transforming the sub-values (the non-atomic ones) were all equal to the original. I added this only in the branch that handles `Constructable`s.)

Comment: Interesting. Is that code available? I have ended up doing lost of jump-through-hoops to include everything that needs to be copied into the default constructor :|

Comment: @the_great_monkey: I do :) I even link to that page as well as parts of the source code

Comment: I can supply my modified version, of course. But some caveats are in order: 1) It's based on a now-superceded version of Kiama; 2) Because I plucked one module (Rewriter.scala) from the Kiama source, I also subjected it to my tender formatting mercies. I did keep a copy of the re-formatted but unmodified version so I can see what deltas I applied. Let me know if you'd like it, I'll put it in a public place.

Comment: Ahh okay I see! What was I thinking?!

Comment: @Randall: Sure! it would be interesting.